# Saving a XML in SQL-Server as varbinary(MAX) or as XML field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to store XMLs in a column in SQL Server. I have found that in some places people recommend a varbinary field and, in others, a XML field.

I know that I can use XQuery on it with a XML field, but, has it any extra advantages? What are the advantages of the varbinary field in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Refer : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-xml-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Comment: in the "some places people recommend a varbinary field" what reason do they give?

Comment: Ah one possible reason in Gehan's link *An identical copy of the data is stored. This is useful for special-purpose applications such as legal documents. Most applications do not require an exact copy and are satisfied with the XML content (InfoSet fidelity).*

Comment: You say they "some people recommend" but then don't annotate or quote any of the source material, so we can't validate their reasoning. The `xml` datatype is designed for storing XML data, and if the ideal data type for storing XML data. Just like the `date` datatype is designed for Dates, and should be used for dates, and the `int` for integers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user needs to cite the resources they are questions for us to be able to answer this question. Without citations, we do not know what "advantages" it is they are speaking of, and cannot answer this questions appropriately.